# Вывод во view пустой результат ActiveRecord.YII2

Tags: php, yii2

Я только что начал изучать Yii2 и сразу столкнулся с недопониманием того, как выводить результат запроса к базе во view. Создал таблицу post и пытаюсь вытянуть из нее массив данных. Вроде все логично но не работает.
**Модель: localhost\yii2-basic\models\Post.php**

```
namespace app\models;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;


class Post extends ActiveRecord
{
     public static function tableName()
     {
         return 'post';
     }
}
```

**Контроллер: localhost\yii2-basic\controllers\PostController.php**

```
namespace app\controllers;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\Post;

class PostController extends Controller
{
   public function actionIndex(){
       $posts = Post::find()->all();
       return $this->render('index', compact('posts'));
   }
}
```

**Вьюха:  localhost\yii2-basic\views\post\index.php**

```
var_dump($posts);
```

При попытке вывода, phpstorm уже тебе говорит что эта переменная `$posts` не объявлена и подчеркивает ее. Почему так происходит? Вроде контроллер должен ее рендерить во вью, но этого не происходит. Подскажите почему так происходит?

Comment: return $this->render('index', ['posts' => $posts]) ?

Comment: Я бы не рекомендовал использовать compact. Вообще все вот эти функции которые забирают/отдают переменные из контекста давно пора удалить или хотя-бы задепрекейтить - они зло и говнокод.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шторм подчеркивает переменную во вьюхе потому что ему неизвестно какие переменные переданы во вьюху. Чтобы шторму подсказать, можно добавить комментарий в самом начале файла.

```
/**
 * @var $this yii\web\View
 * @var $posts array
 */
```

Теперь, если будем использовать другие вьюхи в текущей, то шторм будет знать, что $this это объект View и выдаст подсказки. Также не будет "ругаться" на переменную $posts.

Чтобы узнать почему вьюха не выводит ничего, надо в контроллере проверить, что приходит в переменную.

```
namespace app\controllers;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\Post;

class PostController extends Controller
{
   public function actionIndex(){
       $posts = Post::find()->all();
       var_dump($posts); // смотрим, что в переменной до вьюхи.
       return $this->render('index', compact('posts'));
   }
}
```